# Problem with url encoding on debian sources.list

Tags: debian, apt, repository, url

I am trying to add a repository (datastax) to my sources. This repository ask you to add your username and password, and [also warn that you will have to urlencode special characters](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.1/opsc/install/opscInstallDeb_t.html).

So I added:

```
deb https://user@mail.com:p@ssword@debian.datastax.com/enterprise stable main
```

But `apt-get update` say:

```
W: Failed to fetch https://ssword@debian.datastax.com/enterprise/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Could not resolve host: ssword@debian.datastax.com
```

At this point, I just changed `@` for `%40`:

```
deb https://user%40mail.com:p%40ssword@debian.datastax.com/enterprise stable main
```

But no dice, the error stay the exact same.

Before changing my password to remove any special character and hoping the error will not move to not finding `mail.com:password@debian.datastax.com`, could someone explain what I failed to understand in how apt-get work with special character and password protected repo?

Answer (score 1):

The `@` character is a reserved character in URLs.

Per [**RFC 3986, Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax**, section 2.2, Reserved Characters][1]:

**2.2.  Reserved Characters**

> URIs include components and subcomponents that are delimited by
> characters in the "reserved" set.  These characters are called
> "reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
> the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
> implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm.
> If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved
> character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be
> percent-encoded before the URI is formed.
>
> ```
> reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
> gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>               / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```
>
> The purpose of reserved characters is to provide a set of delimiting
> characters that are distinguishable from other data within a URI.
> URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its
> corresponding percent-encoded octet are not equivalent.  Percent-
> encoding a reserved character, or decoding a percent-encoded octet
> that corresponds to a reserved character, will change how the URI is
> interpreted by most applications.  Thus, characters in the reserved
> set are protected from normalization and are therefore safe to be
> used by scheme-specific and producer-specific algorithms for
> delimiting data subcomponents within a URI.

Note that `@` is listed as one of the "gen-delims".
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2

Comment: Any hint on how to include it in a password in an URL?

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't see how you can do that - "reserved" means you can't use it in any part of a URL as anything other than a separator character.

Comment: But... that rules out many character commonly used in passwords. That's really odd.

Comment: @Kusalananda And that's just *another* reason putting passwords into URLs is a really bad idea. Read [**3.2.1.  User Information**](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.1) of the RFC:  *Use of the format "user:password" in the userinfo field is
   deprecated. ... The
   passing of authentication information in clear text has proven to be
   a security risk in almost every case where it has been used.*

Comment: Good point indeed. The only thing I'm missing from the answer is "how to solve it".

Comment: @Kusalananda You only asked "what I failed to understand" in your question.  Offhand, I suspect the only solutions are to either use a non-password authentication scheme (an SSL certificate signed by the proper authority might work given the use of HTTPS), or to change your password to not use any of the reserved characters.

Comment: Not my question, but I must say I'm intrigued by it.

Comment: @Kusalananda *Not my question*  Ah, my mistake.  It is an interesting question.

Comment: While that explain why it crashes in the first case, it doesn't explain why it still dont find the right domain when the @ is urlencoded.

Comment: @Andrew I may have worded my question better, what I fail to understand is not why it cut at @, but why apt-get still cut on the wrong place with the urlencoded version.

Comment: @DrakaSAN *why apt-get still cut on the wrong place with the urlencoded version.* Oh. [**2.1.  Percent-Encoding**](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1) does seem to state that the encoded value should be parsed as part of the password. If `apt-get` is passing the URL unchanged to the server, I'd venture that it's a bug on the server side. Can you snoop your network traffic and verify that the URL is in fact sent unmodified?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Sorry, took some time to snoop. The URL seems to be modified before, since the DNS query is for `ssword@debian.datastax.com`. What is really strange is that it have a `@` in the middle of the hostname and doesn't seems to be shocked by that.

Answer (score 0):

## Use an APT authentication configuration file

APT uses a separate configuration file for authentication (this information does not go in the "APT line" in the configuration file), these files are located in `/etc/apt/auth.conf.d/` and take the following syntax for your use case:

```
machine FQDN login USERNAME password PASSWORD
```

where `FQDN` in your case is `debian.datastax.com`, `USERNAME` is `user@mail.com`, and PASSWORD is `p@ssword`.  APT should take care of the rest for you (URL-encoding any special characters) automatically.